# KnownType on existing class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, inheritance

I am creating a service using WCF. One of my service methods should return an instance of a type, which is inherited from `System.Net.WebProxy`. Because of the inheritance, the WCF would not know which type is meant (this is well-known, I guess). The "work-around" would be to add the KnownTypeAttribute to my base class, which is in this case `System.Net.WebProxy`. But `System.Net.WebProxy` is a framework type, therefore I can not change it.

How can I get the WCF service return a inherited object, which I can not equip with the KnownTypeAttribute *or* how can I equip the existing class with the KnownTypeAttribute?

**Edit:** I tried to use an empty intermediate ancestor from my base class, which I decorated with the KnownTypeAttribute and then let my real class inherit from that intermediate type. This does neither work out.

Best regards

Comment: Why you don't add inherited class to KnownTypeAttribute?

Comment: I can't, because the base class is a framework-owned class.

Comment: Could you perhaps introduce an intermediate, empty ancestor (inherited from System.Net.WebProxy) that you can then decorate with the KnownType attribute?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Tried that, didn't worked out.